# Objects initialization

Tags: c++

I want to build a framework in C++ and the fact that C++ has no built-in c#-like reflection feature is a difficulty.

The problem I'm trying to solve is : I have an object, I will know the name of its class at runtime (as a string), and I will know the name of its properties at runtime too (as strings). Then I'm wondering what it is the best way to create an instance of this class at runtime and to put default values in its properties without having to create another constructor.

Also, I would like to avoid using third-party librairies like boost, and compilers specific features.

Thanks for your help, any hint/idea would be appreciated !

Comment: On which operating system? With which compiler? What standard revision (C++11 or older)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for now let us say on Windows. I was actually hoping to keep it cross-platform

Comment: Your question says that the class and property names are strings determined at run-time, but your code shows them as known at compile time. What do you actually need to do?

Comment: Yes, I think the code sample is confusing, sorry about that. The class is defined in the code, however the name of the class I want to instanciate will be known at runtime

Comment: Can you explain the corelation between your snippet and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Then fix the code sample, or at least remove it. As you can see from the given answers, it will just confuse people.

Comment: It's removed, thanks a lot. I forgot to remove it, I was thinking about how to formulate my problem and I didn't realize the snippet became unecessary and confusing

Comment: Why do you ask, what framework have you in mind, with what C++ compiler and operating system? (Linux could be easier than Windows).

Comment: I would like to write an ORM since I've found that there is no decent, free as in beer and OpenSource C++ ORM. I'm still in the early stages of the project and since I'm more a C# guy and I haven't touched C++ for a while, I need to revisit the language basics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible (to instantiate a class by its name at runtime) in purely standard C++, since C++11 does not have reflection.

However, you could consider things like

- adding your own meta-object protocol, like Qt does (see its `moc`)
- having your own conventions and using X-macro tricks
- customizing your C++ compiler, e.g. if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) extending it with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)
- use factory design pattern coupled with dynamic linking à la [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)

I would suggest to define in your framework some conventions, and implement tools, to fit your needs. For instance you might define your own root class and add C++ code generators  (like `moc` in Qt) to help you.

Look also into frameworks like [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/f) (and of course [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)).

Comment: + using factory design pattern

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That's not a good new at all, reflection is really a missing feature of C++. @PiotrS. How is possible to achieve this with factory pattern ? Because then, I'll need extra constructors isn't it ?

Comment: @red2nb: not "constructor" but factory method/object that creates/fetches object based on string provided

Comment: Well thank you. I'll need to dig into it to properly understand it, but the factory design pattern + dlopen seems to answer my question even though I feel like dynamic linking will introduce a overhead I didn't wanted. I'll try to learn more about it to see how it works in more details, and I hope I'll be able to abstract that for the end user.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Blog
{
public:
    Blog(string  t, string d) : title(t), description(d) {}
    string getTitle() {return title;}
    void setTitle(string t) {title = t;}
    // etc...

private:
    string title;
    string description;
}
```

then to init

```
Blog *blog = new Blog {"The Title", "Blog description"};
```

Comment: That definitely is not what OP asks for

Answer (score 1):

```
class Blog
{
  public:
     Blog() {}
     Blog(std::string s1, std::string s2): Title(s1), Description(s2){}
     // add get, set methods separately as required
     // alternately, you may declare Title, Description as public:
  private:
     std::string Title;
     std::string Description;

}

...Then we use it somewhere

Blog blog = new Blog("The Title", "Blog description");
```

Comment: This is not what OP asks for

Comment: But, someone has to write the code, even for Factory pattern